# utcOffset in moment.js doesn`t work properly

Tags: momentjs

utcOffset doesn`t work in calculating time difference

```
let futureEvent=moment("12.9.2020:23:30","DD.MM.YYYY:hh:mm")
let currentTime=moment().utcOffset(1)
console.log(currentTime)
console.log(futureEvent.diff(currentTime,'hours'))
```

The problem is that utcOffset affects only on currentTime but it doesn`t influence time difference (second console log).

currentTime is setted with correct utc offset(checked by first console log)

Has anyone some ideas?

Comment: what is your expected output here ? what difference you are expecting

Comment: When I set different utcOffset in currentTime I expect that difference in time will be different. For instance without utcOffset diff is 2 hours (I am in time zone +3) but because of setting utcOffset to 1 it must be 4 hours. But utcOffset affects only on currentTime as I said in description

Comment: Sorry but i still do not understand you are saying *currentTime is setted with correct utc offset(checked by first console log)*  whats the problem here then ?

Comment: The problem is that it calculates diff without affecting offset